# All elements filter but hovered

Tags: html, css

How to select all elements except the one hovered and add a filter (like blur or brightness)

like this
[image]

I have tried

`.class:hover *:not(.class:hover)`

this is not working.

And if using the parent div, filter is overlay. How can I solve this?

Comment: please provide a working jsfiddle to play around the code !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is on `hover` of `Child` Element rest of `Child` is filter

```css
.parent .child:not(:hover) {
  color:#00ffff;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(1);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(1);
  filter: grayscale(1);
  opacity: .75;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child">Child 3</div>
</div>
```

and using parent `Hover`

```css
.parent:hover .child:not(:hover) {
  color:#00ffff;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(1);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(1);
  filter: grayscale(1);
  opacity: .75;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child">Child 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Use `.class:not(:hover)` which filters all elements with class `.class` but not hovered